# How to access window and document in Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to get active window's cookie information in an extension built with the Add-on SDK. How can I do this? I couldn't find any method in documentation that has access to window or document. Also in [some forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2120501#profile10487627), folks talk about there is no way to access to them. Is it really not possible still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access document and therefore document.cookie via a content script; for more on working with content scripts, see the documentation:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/modifying-web-pages-url.html

Edit: here's a simple example that allows you to fetch cookie data for the current tab into the addon's main code:

https://github.com/canuckistani/jp-page-mod-cookie

Comment: These links are broken now.

Comment: The links are broken :(

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed now.

Comment: I want to constantly capture if the mouse is moving or not. And of course I cannot do this because I don't have access to document or window. Any idea on how to do that without modifying each new tab to include this script ?

Comment: @David天宇Wong: the active tab is found via `tabs.on("activate", function ()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Access_tabs